# Conditional variable assignment without else

Tags: javascript, variables, variable-assignment

I get a variable from service, it can be true, false or undefined. If it is true or false I must keep it, otherwise I must set to true;

I was figuring out how to make it and I used:

```
  obj.foo != false && (obj.foo = true);
```

Is there a best way to make it? I mean, I can use a ternary operator, but in some cases my variable will already be false/true, then I don't need the else statement of the ternary.

Comment: You're assigning it in your if statement. Post the whole snippet.

Comment: `obj.foo = obj.foo !== undefined ? obj.foo : true`

Comment: Maybe like this? `foo === undefined || foo === true`

Answer (score 2):

I think this would work: `foo === undefined || foo`

```js
var foo = undefined;
console.log(foo === undefined || foo);

var foo = true;
console.log(foo === undefined || foo);

var foo = false;
console.log(foo === undefined || foo);
```

Comment: You can even try `foo === undefined || foo`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work:

```
function invokeMe () {
  var objectsArray = [{name: "object1", trueOrNot: true}, 
                {name: "object2", trueOrNot: false},
                {name: "object3", trueOrNot: ''}
               ];
  objectsArray.forEach(function (object) {
  object.trueOrNot = object.trueOrNot !== false ? true : false;
  console.log(object);
});
}

invokeMe();
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xyekq0c6/2/)

Comment: that code always set the value to true, doesn't it?

Comment: No - that will set the value to true, only if obj.foo = undefined (or if its actual value was true from the beginning).
As I understood of the post, the value should only NOT be true, if it is FALSE. So if obj.foo = false, this code will just set obj.foo equal to its actual value - meaning false. :)

Comment: Wrap up: 

If Obj.foo = true, obj.foo will stay true. 

If obj.foo = false, obj.foo will stay false.

If obj.foo = undefined, obj.foo will be set to true.

Comment: Hmm, it seem you were correct - I might have done something different in past, when I did something like this, than I remember. Have made a Jsfiddle now with a similar example. editting comment